# Как вывести массив из массива в новый?

Tags: php

У меня есть массив:

```
Array
(
[data_list] => Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
      [sales] => Array
    )
     [0] => Array
    (
     [sale_id] => 29  
     ) 
     [1] => Array
     (
     [sale_id] => 29
     )  
  )      
 )
)
```

Как мне вывести массив sales в новый с сохранением внутренних массивов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArray = $oldArray['data_list'][0]['sales'];
var_export($newArray);
```

Где $oldArray - ваш массив.